# Generating views from API call - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, swiftui-state

I'm new to SwiftUI, and was wondering if someone could help me make my app work. Also I'm trying to get my head around MVVM, and was wondering if I was doing it correctly.

The app makes a call to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users and I'm trying to generate user cards based on the json response.

**Model:**

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - User
class User: Codable {
    
    
    let id: Int
    let name, username, email: String
    let address: Address
    let phone, website: String
    let company: Company

    init(id: Int, name: String, username: String, email: String, address: Address, phone: String, website: String, company: Company) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
        self.website = website
        self.company = company
    }
}

// MARK: - Address
class Address: Codable {
    let street, suite, city, zipcode: String
    let geo: Geo

    init(street: String, suite: String, city: String, zipcode: String, geo: Geo) {
        self.street = street
        self.suite = suite
        self.city = city
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.geo = geo
    }
}

// MARK: - Geo
class Geo: Codable {
    let lat, lng: String

    init(lat: String, lng: String) {
        self.lat = lat
        self.lng = lng
    }
}

// MARK: - Company
class Company: Codable {
    let name, catchPhrase, bs: String

    init(name: String, catchPhrase: String, bs: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.catchPhrase = catchPhrase
        self.bs = bs
    }
}

typealias Users = [User]
```

**View:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserView: View {
    let user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(user.name)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Text(user.email)
                .font(.callout)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .textCase(.uppercase)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .cornerRadius(10.0)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
import SwiftUI

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: Users = []
    
    init() {
        fetchUsers()
    }
    
    func fetchUsers() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users") else { print("Invalid url")
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("There was an error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Users.self, from: data)
                print("success: \(userData.capacity)")
            } catch let parsingError {
                print("There was an error: \(parsingError.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
        
    }
}
```

And I want to display it in a **UserContainerView:**

```
struct UserContainer: View {
    let uservm = UserViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: uservm.fetchUsers, label: {
                Text("Fetch some users boy")
            })
            
            ForEach(uservm.users, id: \.id, content: { user in
                UserView(user: user)
            })
            
            Spacer()
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

**My problem is** not a single UserView is displayed, because the array of Users passed to UserView is empty. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? I don't have a solid grasp on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have view model as observed, like

```
struct UserContainer: View {
    @ObservedObject var uservm = UserViewModel()
```

and assign parsed users, like

```
do {
    let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Users.self, from: data)
    print("success: \(userData.capacity)")

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
       self?.users = userData    // make sure if correct type here - cannot test
    }
} catch let parsingError {
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfect. I don't understand that DispatchQueue closure that well, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

(Picking up where @Asperi left out since his/her answer will solve your problem)

Based on your code it looks like this part may give you trouble

```
  import SwiftUI

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: Users = []
      ...
    }
```

Rather it should be

```
   import SwiftUI

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = []
    }
```

And to add to the previous answer, since the suggestion was to cast it directly `self?.users = userData` there is one adjustment that should be made :

```
let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Users].self, from: data)
```

The only change being that you're decoding it into an array since that is what you selected your publisher to be in your viewModel.

Comment: Thanks, Users is typealias for [User], I think it worked correctly.